# Does Datomic ship all transactions to all connected peers on "commit"?

Tags: datomic

The Datomic [transactor pushes live changes to all connected peers](http://docs.datomic.com/architecture.html) to maintain a [*Live Index*](http://docs.datomic.com/indexes.html).

Does that mean that **all data** that gets transacted will always be sent to all peers connected - interested in the data or not? Or is it only e.g. the most recent db transaction id?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The empirically reached answer: **Yes, the full contents of all transactions (and more *) gets streamed to all connected peers**.

I confirmed that by connecting a peer A to a transactor and let it either

1. just sit there, staying connected OR
2. monitor transactions by means of [`tx-report-queue`](http://docs.datomic.com/clojure/index.html#datomic.api/tx-report-queue) OR
3. monitor transactions and print all attribute values of all entities that were modified in the transaction

Concurrent to each of the above test runs, a peer B would execute 4 transactions, where each transaction would change a couple of simple properties of a single entity, one of the attributes being the about 5k random string data, the other attributes just really short strings.

Wireshark captured the TCP connection between Peer A and the transactor, and the **total byte size of the tcp dumps can be seen in the following table**.

```
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
  case  tx-report-queue  print  bytes (5kB)  bytes (13kB) 
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
     1                                61348        127996 
     2  ✓                             61800        128084 
     3  ✓                ✓            61260        127652 
──────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 no-tx                                13076         12988 
━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━
```

The relative dump sizes differ by less than 500 Bytes, which is far less than even a single of the 4 committed transactions, that change more than 5kB each, incur.

I then also ran the test without doing any transactions, and the tcp dump would then shrink to about 13kB. I therefore take it that it is transaction data being transmitted.

***)** Back-of-the-envelope: **The per transaction cost of transactor<->PeerA data was about `(61kB-13kB)/4tx = 12kB/tx`**. So it looks that when changing a property, **both the retraction (5kB for that one string) and addition (again 5kB) are transmitted via the transactor's live index**, which would give about 10kB, plus a little spare room of 2kB for the other (much smaller) modified attributes, (plus some more heart beats, which occur every 5 seconds and add some 300 Bytes, in the test cases where transactions were performed, just because of the time I took to run those tests).

**Edit** To put my inferences on more solid a foundation, I reran the tests with a 13kB string instead of the original 5k. The results (added to the table) seem to confirm my theory: Now the per-transaction cost is about `(128kB-13kB)/4tx = 29kB/tx`, so 13kB retraction + 13kB addition + 3kB slack.

---

**Further Edit** I ran some more tests, graphing the bytes received by the respective PeerA*s. Both traffic from the transactor, which was done via a single TCP connection, and traffic from the `datomic:free://` (i.e. [H2](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html)) storage, which in all cases involved three TCP connections to the same H2 port.

I ignored TCP traffic in the direction of the transactor and storage, which was much less.

- **PeerA1** starts with an empty database

  1. monitors transactions via [`tx-report-queue`]
  2. prints all attribute values of all entities modified in every transaction
  3. queries all elements in the database every 4 seconds
- **PeerB** performs the above 13kB string attribute change and a few other very small attribute changes every 6 seconds
- **PeerA2** starts with a populated database and PeerB still running

  1. monitors transactions via [`tx-report-queue`]
  2. prints all attribute values of all entities modified in every transaction
- **PeerA3** starts with a populated database and PeerB still running

  1. monitors transactions via [`tx-report-queue`]
- **PeerA4** starts with a populated database and PeerB still running

  1. does nothing besides connecting to datomic and waiting

And here's a chart of the rx traffic (of the PeerA*s):

[image]

How I read the chart:

- the transactor always pushes tx data on commit, whether PeerA is interested in it or not
- the transaction data contains, in addition to the data "additions", the implicit retractions (that's why the first transactor spike after starting PeerB is only half the size of later spikes - the first time there is no data yet, hence nothing to retract)
- storage is only used initially to read (from the log in storage - not from the index - as the data in the database is always much less than `memory-index-threshold=32m`, i.e. indexing will not kick in during the test)
- storage is not used when PeerA1 queries the database; in fact, the queries do not incur any noticable network traffic
- storage read size when starting the peers grows as the db accretes data (regardless of the fact that data is "overwritten" -> datomic history)